# Using asp.net 2.0 book with Visual Studio 2010 Master Page ContentPlaceHolder + Tables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, master-pages

I'm currently working at an internship and having no real background experience in programming, they give me a 24-hour book about asp.net 2.0 VB but I'm using Visual Studio 2010 instead of 2005. Plus, the book is using more of the Design view more than the source view. I'm at the Master Page chapter and it's telling me to use tables as site-wide templates. Here's the problem:

It's telling me to go to the layout menu (which doesn't exist or I can't find it). So I find a table menu instead, so I go into insert tables. The book says there should be a template drop down menu with a header, footer, and side. There isn't one and I can't find it anywhere else.

The question: Is it still available in 2010 or is there something else in its place that i should use?

Answer (score 0):

Layout menu is no more there since VS2005

In Visual Studio 2010 on Design View (The bottom "Design" button should be enabled) go to the main upper menu and choose:

Tools - Options - CSS Styling and Check the option
"Change position to absolute for controls added using Toolbox,paste or drag and drop"

However I don't recommend this because in my experience is not browser compatible sometimes so you should permanently check how your page looks in different browsers as you go forward in your layout.

You can try to create your tables manually (with the menu you just found) instead and use their css properties to align the text/images inside each row and cell as you wish. This can help to walk you through the process:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/csharpgeneral/thread/7db5a810-e9e0-42eb-8ebc-a4c28036effc

http://forums.asp.net/t/1599099.aspx/1

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/dyxa0hhe.aspx

Hope this helps.